# Determine tallest/shortest person in a group

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to java and am tasked with some work that i am stuck on.

The task is to write a java program that find the shortest and tallest people in a group, in which the number of people of the group is unknown. The program is to ask the first name and height (in metres) of each person. The height is to be validated within the range of 0.8m to 2.5m. The program must then display the name and height of the shortest and tallest person within the group. Also the use of arrays and ArrayLists is not allowed.

I would appreciate it If anyone could point me in the right direction as currently i can't seem the wrap my head around the problem.

EDIT: i have written the code for the program after some helpful comments below, except i am having a problem with the program printing null values. Below is the code.

```
package pracset1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class shortTall {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    String maxname = null;
    String minname = null;
    double height;
    double maxheight = -1.0d;
    double minheight = 1000.0d;
    char addperson;
    String choice;
    
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter first name of person");
        name = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter height of person");
        height = keyboard.nextDouble();
    
        if (height < 0.8 || height > 2.5)
        {
            System.out.println("Entered height must be above 0.8m and below 2.5m");
            height = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        
        if (height > maxheight)
        {
            maxheight = height;
            maxname = name;
        }
            else if (height < minheight)
            {
                minheight = height;
                minname = name;
            }
        
        System.out.println("Do you want to add another person? (Y/N)");
        choice = keyboard.next();
        addperson = choice.charAt(0);
    }
        while (addperson == 'Y' || addperson == 'y');   // 
    
    System.out.println("Tallest person is " + maxname + " with a height of " + maxheight);
    System.out.println("Shortest person is " + minname + " with a height of " + minheight);
        
}
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the problem

[image: null]

Comment: You need to post some of your code, reffering to your problem.

Comment: Assume you were doing this by hand with pen and paper. Can you try to come up with an algorithm and post your attempt here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
double maxheight = -1.0d;
double minheight = 1000.0d;
String maxname = "";
String minname = "";

while (true)
{
    String name = System.console().readLine();
    double height = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine());

    if(height < 0.8 || height > 2.5)
    {
        System.out.println("%d is to large or to small", height);
        continue;
    }

    if (height > maxheight)
    {
        maxname = name;
        maxheight = height;
    }

    if (height < minheight)
    {
        minname = name;
        minheight = height;
    }

    System.out.println("%s is heighest person with %d meters", maxname, maxheight);
    System.out.println("%s is lowest person with %d meters", minname, minheight);
}
```

You would need to do some additional stuff like letting the user exit the program. But you get the idea?

**EDIT:**

The code should look like this:

```
package pracset1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class shortTall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        String maxname = null;
        String minname = null;
        double height;
        double maxheight = -1.0d;
        double minheight = 1000.0d;
        char addperson;
        String choice;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter first name of person");
            name = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter height of person");
            height = keyboard.nextDouble();

            while (height < 0.8 || height > 2.5)
            {
                System.out.println("Entered height must be above 0.8m and below 2.5m");
                height = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }

            if (height > maxheight)
            {
                maxheight = height;
                maxname = name;
            }

            if (height < minheight)
            {
                minheight = height;
                minname = name;
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to add another person? (Y/N)");
            choice = keyboard.next();
            addperson = choice.charAt(0);
        }
        while (addperson == 'Y' || addperson == 'y');   // 

        System.out.println("Tallest person is " + maxname + " with a height of " + maxheight);
        System.out.println("Shortest person is " + minname + " with a height of " + minheight);

    }
}
```

By changing the first if statement into a while loop. The program execution will not continue until you have a valid height entered.

By changing the last else if statement into if statement. The first valid person entered will become both the tallest and the smallest person.

Comment: `string` with lower `s`? Seriously?

Comment: thank you, based on this i was able to write up the program. Although not all of the functionality seems to work, i have updated my original post with the code i have written and a screenshot of the problem if you can provide any further assistance.

Comment: change the first if statement to a while loop. This way program execution will only continue when you have a valid height

Comment: remove the "else" in the last "else if". This way the first person entered will become the tallest and the smallest which makes sense. And there will be no more null people :)

Comment: I have edited my answer with a modification of your code that will work

Comment: Thank you! That has fixed the problem and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

This is the pseudocode.

`Get name and height from input;
if (currentheight>maxHeight) then maxHeight = currentheight; maxName = currentName;
else if (currentheight<minHeight) then minHeight = currentheight; minName = currentName;
Ask if user wants to add one more person;
if yes go back to step 1;
if no print maxName + maxHeight + minName + minHeight;`

Just have a for loop asking whether user wants to add someone else to the group, change min and max accordingly. And then print them.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code the algorithm would look something like this:

Keep variables for the name and height for the tallest and shortest person.

1. Get input
2. Validate input
3. If input is valid set the variables to current input if current height is taller than previously recorded tallest height and vice versa for the shortest if current height is lower than previous recorded shortest.
4. If there is more input return to 1.
5. If there's no more input the variables now hold the name and height of the tallest and shortest persons.

Finished.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways we can look at this problem. I thought any sorting algorithm can fix this problem statement assuming you have set of heigths before hand.

I went ahead with Bubble Sort approach. For better complexity you can do it through Quick Sort as well. But if the number of persons is small then no harm in going with Bubble Sort.

As a real time standard solution you might want to have better naming conventions, null checks, exception handling, valdation logic etc.

Below is code snippet.

```
public class MaxMinHeightFinder {

    // logic to sort the elements
    public static void sortIndividualsByHeight(double array[]) {
        int n = array.length;
        int k;
        for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                k = i + 1;
                if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                    swapNumbers(i, k, array);
                }
            }
        }
        printHeights(array);
    }

    private static void swapNumbers(int i, int j, double[] array) {

        double temp;
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    private static void printHeights(double[] input) {

        //System.out.println(""+ Arrays.toString(input));

        System.out.println("Min Height : "+ input[0]);

        System.out.println("Max Height : "+ input[input.length-1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] heights = { 4.0, 2.5, 9.6, 6.4, 23.2, 12.6, 14.4, 7.5, 1.4 };
        sortIndividualsByHeight(heights);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you read the question from the OP you can see that arrays and ArrayLists are not allowed